# Google Geocoding Request limit

Tags: android

Please let me know the full detail of request limit of `Geo-coding`. It is given on web site but here are few things which is not clear to me.

​2,500 requests per 24 hour period for each device or for one application?

What is the maximum request limit for one application and for one device?

Answer (score 0):

*Server-side* GeoCoding API is limited as you exposed, by API key (so applications), not devices.

However, Google has this to say about "when to use *client-side* geocoding":

> The basic answer is "almost always." As geocoding limits are per user session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally don't have to worry about your quota.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client

- So I strongly recommend you move your GeoCoding code to the client side.
- If you can't, you'll take the risk to hit that 2500 limit / 24 hours.